# How to find the roots of this polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $s\in\mathbb{Z}$, $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we have the following equation
$$\bigg((-1)^{s-1}x^{2s-2}-ibx+a\bigg)\bigg((-1)^{s-1}x^{2s-2}+ibx+a\bigg)=0$$
How would I go about finding its roots (in $\mathbb{C}$)? I think it makes sense to split into the cases where s is even or odd, but im still not sure what to do, the terms with $b$ in them are throwing me off.

Comment: Do you have some reason to expect there is a nice way to express the roots?

Comment: This problem finds its application in physics, where $x^2=p^2=p_{\mu}p^{\mu}$ is the momentum squared. Originally it was a PDE which I fourier transformed to momentum space... I am trying to solve for the momentum squared to obtain the corresponding mass in terms of $a$ and $b$, so I am only hoping there is some nice solution.

Comment: So to answer your question; No reason other than a fools hope.

Comment: Minor pet peeve: it's $i^2=-1$, not $i=\sqrt{-1}$. The difference is subtle, but one of the reasons why I care is that teaching the latter legitimises unthinkingly using the square root symbol on complex numbers.